# Wordpress delete categorie filter

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress Widget to filter my photos but I want to delete the "All" Filter-Categorie and it´s not possible in the Widget settings. So I tried with custom css:

```css
main a.data-vp-filter {display: none}
```

But it doesn't work.

The code of the All-Categorie:

[image]

The All-Categorie I want to delete:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the filter items have the same class you could add the following to your custom css:

```
.vp-filter .vp-filter__item:first-of-type {
   display: none !important; 
}
```

This will select the first-type of class. [MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

**Preview:**

```css
.vp-filter .vp-filter__item:first-of-type {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="vp-filter">
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>All</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>Filter 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>Filter 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>Filter 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>Filter 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>Filter 5</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vp-filter__item">
    <a>Filter 6</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first one works, thanks! But how can I change it that the first filter (Automotiv) is selected?